# How to create a same user in different PDB while it exists in other PDBs?

Tags: oracle, linux, configuration, plsql, users

I have a list of 100 PDBs in the CDB, say the account_user exists in 50 PDBs and to create the same account_user in other 50 PDBs instead of logging into each PDB and creating user, is there a way to do this with single command or script?

When I create the user from CDB, I get below error:

ORA-01920: user name 'account_user' conflicts with another user or role name

nor container=all will work coz I don't want to drop the user form first 50 PDBs and re-create all over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> select pdb_name from cdb_pdbs order by 1;

PDB_NAME
--------------------
PDB$SEED
PDB1
PDB2
PDB3

SQL> select u.username, p.pdb_name from cdb_users u 
     join cdb_pdbs p on (u.con_id = p.pdb_id) where u.username = 'BP';

USERNAME             PDB_NAME
-------------------- --------------------
BP                   PDB1
```

Just generate the script:

```
SQL> select 'alter session set container=' ||pdb_name || ';' || chr(10) || 'CREATE USER BP IDENTIFIED BY BP;' as script from cdb_pdbs p where not exists (select 1 from cdb_users u where u.username = 'BP' and u.con_id = pdb_id) and pdb_name not in ('CDB$ROOT', 'PDB$SEED') ;

SCRIPT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
alter session set container=PDB3;
CREATE USER BP IDENTIFIED BY BP;

alter session set container=PDB2;
CREATE USER BP IDENTIFIED BY BP;
```

Then execute it:

```
SQL>

alter session set container=PDB3;
CREATE USER BP IDENTIFIED BY BP;

alter session set container=PDB2;
CREATE USER BP IDENTIFIED BY BP;

Session altered.

SQL>
User created.

SQL> SQL>
Session altered.

SQL>
User created.

SQL> alter session set container=CDB$ROOT;

Session altered.

SQL> select u.username, p.pdb_name from cdb_users u
     join cdb_pdbs p on (u.con_id = p.pdb_id) where u.username = 'BP';

USERNAME             PDB_NAME
-------------------- --------------------
BP                   PDB1
BP                   PDB2
BP                   PDB3

SQL>
```

Comment: Cool, i did the same but by manually editing the create commands in editor right after session alter commands and ran in container. Thanks.Wish there is a bulk user creation process by Oracle in multiple databases

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Each PDB is [*guaranteed* to be] completely separate from every other PDB.
That's kind of the *whole point* of them.

There is *no way* of "influencing" multiple databases at once in the way you describe.

You'll just have script up the change and apply it to each of the 50 databases in turn.

I would go one step further and suggest that, with this many accounts and this many databases to look after, it's probably time to start looking into *automating* your account management process.